# I can't turn off the MATLAB, and error message jumps out

Tags: matlab

I can't turn off my MATLAB recently. I type *exit*, but there is an error message:

> > Error using feof
> >     Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.
> >
> > Error in preserve_history (line 12)
> >     while ~feof(fid)
> >
> > Error in finish (line 3)
> >     preserve_history;

Could any one tell me what's wrong my MATLAB? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a [`finish` script](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/finish.html) that is automatically being run when you try to exit, and it has a bug in it.

Answer (score 2):

does `quit force` work?
It should bypass finish.m